# NotSupportedException on IQuery's Enumerable when using statelesssession

Tags: nhibernate, enumerable, named-query, notsupportedexception

when trying to use the Enumerable method on a named query, with a Stateless session, as shown in the example at:

http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#batch-statelesssession

i am seeing a NotSupportedException. the stack trace is as below:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.Enumerable(String query, QueryParameters parameters)
at NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl.Enumerable()
```

here is a snippet of my code:

```
IStatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession();
var fileLines = statelessSession.GetNamedQuery("GetLinesByFileId")
.SetInt32("FileIdInput", fileId).Enumerable<FileLineEntity>();
```

the named query, GetLinesByFileId is defined in the hbm as below:

```
<query name="GetLinesByFileId" cacheable="false" read-only="true">
    <![CDATA[
        from FileLineEntity lineItem where lineItem.FileId=:FileIdInput 
      ]]>
  </query>
```

any suggestions on what i maybe missing here?

Comment: Bad docs? Current NH Trunk throws that exception. Just use List<>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc is wrong. Also, by looking at it you can tell it's copied from Hibernate (Java).

Use the `List` method instead.