# How to iterate on an entire table using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, iterator

I am looking for a simple NHibernate example which will show me how iterate on an entire table. Here is what I have so far, but it is not working. I am getting an "System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.". What am I doing wrong?

```
    public IEnumerable<EMPDATA> getEMPData()
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            IEnumerable<EMPDATA> empData = session.CreateQuery("from EMPDATA").Enumerable<EMPDATA>();
            return empData;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(System.String[] args)
    {
        log.Debug("Entered main");
        Console.WriteLine("Entered main");
        try
        {
            IEMPDataRepository repository = new EMPDataRepository();
            IEnumerable<EMPDATA> iterList = repository.getEMPData();
            while( iterList.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
            {
                EMPDATA emp = iterList.GetEnumerator().Current;
                log.Debug(emp.EMP_ID);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Exception occured reading emp data", ex);
        }
```

Here is my mapping:

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the entire table?

Comment: I need to iterate over an entire table because I am comparing records in this table to another table and if there are extra rows, I want to insert them into the other table.

Comment: NHibernate is not really the right tool for batch operations in my opinion - the best solution would depend on your reasons for needed to do this.

Comment: Then you should do that at the database level, not pulling them all into memory and attempting to achieve the same thing. Just write a stored proc with a cursor. It would perform 10x better than doing a SELECT+N on the tables.

Comment: I agree that it is not the right tool for batch operations. But is there a way do it? I just do not want to persist these records in memory which is why I am trying to iterate on them.

Comment: Why are you using NHibernate if you want to iterate over a table ?  Using NHibernate means thinking in entities, not in tables.  And, an entity can span multiple tables.

Comment: Without seeing the mapping file it is not possible to see whether the query is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You request an Enumerable result, which probably relies on the session still beeing open.

since you Dispose the session after returning the Enumerable instance, you have closed the connection to the database.

EDIT: see [NotSupportedException on IQuery's Enumerable when using statelesssession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503445/notsupportedexception-on-iquerys-enumerable-when-using-statelesssession)

Comment: Actually looking at the NHibernate code, Enumerable executes the queries when it's called. He'd be getting a disposed session exception otherwise.

Comment: If you want to enumerate large amounts of data with NHibernate it also makes sense to use a stateless session to avoid storing all read entities in the first-level cache.

Comment: Execution query and iterating through the resultset is two different things, but you might be right, I haven't looked.

Comment: Thanks, I will look and see if the session is being closed, I am not explicitly closing the connection.

Comment: closing the session also forces to close db access

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `.List` instead of `.Enumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

Longer answer:
1. I agree with Phill- looks like a job for a SP
2. Diego is (obviously) right, but if I were you i'd use SetFirstResult() and  SetMaxResult() in order to control the amount of data you load into memory in each iteration (don't forget to sort by something when using this method, of course).